# Daylight saving causing issue with scheduled job timing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduled-tasks

I have a materialized view `MVIEW_MY_AU` which is getting refreshed from a stored procedure named `REFRESH_MVIEWS_VIA_PRC`. This SP contains following statement :

```
dbms_mview.refresh('MVIEW_MY_AU');
```

A job `REFRESH_MVIEWS_VIA_SCH` is created in all_scheduler_jobs table to execute this stored procedure.

Query :

```
select job_name, last_start_date,next_run_date,job_action from all_scheduler_jobs 
where job_name = 'REFRESH_MVIEWS_VIA_SCH'
```

Output :

[image]

As per the scheduled job I am expecting this materialized view to get refresh at 3:30 AM Australia time. But when its getting refreshed at 4:30 AM Australia time as per the following query :

Query :

```
SELECT LAST_REFRESH              
,TO_CHAR(last_refresh, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS A.M.') as LAST_REFRESH_TIME 
FROM user_mview_refresh_times
where name like 'MVIEW_MY_AU'
```

Output :

[image]

I started facing this issue after Daylight saving time for Australia started on 2nd Oct 2016. Is there any way to schedule the job which will take into consideration the day light saving time?

Answer (score 0):

The are several ways that Oracle will consider daylight saving times.

Enter `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value for parameter `start_time`, e.g. `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

From [DBMS_SCHEDULER Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72266):

> When start_date is NULL, the Scheduler determines the time zone for
>   the repeat interval as follows:
>
> 1. It checks whether or not the session time zone is a region name. The session time zone can be set by either:
>
>    - Issuing an ALTER SESSION statement, for example:
>        SQL> `ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = 'Asia/Shanghai';`
>    - Setting the `ORA_SDTZ` environment variable.
> 2. If the session time zone is an absolute offset instead of a region name, the Scheduler uses the value of the `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` Scheduler
>      attribute.
> 3. If the `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` attribute is NULL, the Scheduler uses the time zone of systimestamp when the job or window is enabled.

Most important: Time zone must be provided as region, e.g. `Australia/Sydney`, not as UTC offset like `+08:00`

Regarding your query:

Column LAST_REFRESH of view `user_mview_refresh_times` is `DATE` data type, so by definition it does not contain any time zone information. Most likely column `LAST_REFRESH` is provided at your DB operating system server time zone (i.e. time zone value of `SYSDATE`). What is the time zone of your DB operating system server? You can determine this on OS directly or by

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual;
```